# Google Tag/Analytics Standard Ecommerce data not passed to Google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

I have setup google tag manager and enable Standard Ecommerce but can't see to get this to work.

[image: Google Analytics Ecommerce Enabled = ON]

I have set up a trigger to fire on transactionComplete in GTM

[image: Tag and Trigger setup in GTM for type transaction]

And you can see the dataLayer being properly filled!

[image: GTM Debugger -- DataLayer properly populated]

In the variable field - it says ecommerce is not enable (remember - I did enable it).

[image: GA variables indicate ecommerce is not enabled?]

And here is the programmed DataLayer with all the required fields.

[image]

Any guidance much appreciated. Does it really take some time to populate the Google Analytics ecommerce field. I am concerned it is not working because of the flag that indicated it is not enabled.  Thank you for any guidance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the problem is due to the transaction with value 0 together with the product with price 0. I would try to assign at least one price to the product (not to the transaction).